# How to resize a window using WM_* messages

Tags: c++, windows, delphi, winapi

When a window handle is given, how can i exactly resize a window sending windows messages towards it? I've tried many things such as sendig a WM_SIZING Message to the window, but nothing worked(the way i did it).

I don't like to use SetWindowPosition.

Thanks in advance,

David

Comment: Why would you send it a message when you could use the HWND and the SetWindowPos function (which also does size). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545(v=VS.85).aspx, also some code would be useful for context

Comment: Well, there is a strange problem to be solved: an application thats very important to us does some complex calculations that run a few hours. If one klicks on the window border of this wide-spread commercial app and holds the mouse button down, its calculations run several times as fast.

Comment: This blog entry explains your problem: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/02/20/535440.aspx Sending messages is, of course, not the correct solution. Fixing the incorrect code inside of the application is what you want to do. Short of that, you can just minimize its window...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`WM_SIZE` and `WM_SIZING` are not commands, they are notifications sent by `SetWindowPlacement`. You can use that or any of the conveniece API available, including `SetWindowPos` and `MoveWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

I try:

in .h:

```
#define WM_RESIZEMESSAGE        (WM_USER+1)
void ResizeHandler (WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

in .cpp:

```
ON_MESSAGE (WM_RESIZEMESSAGE, ResizeHandler )

void CTestClass::ResizeHandler (WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  int x = 100; //--> desired size
  int y = 100; //-->desired size
  MoveWindow(0, 0, x, y, TRUE); //->Move window

}
```

The above code may not be as you want, because I'm not clear which window you would like to resize, and calling the resize from another class or what...

I just suggest to use MoveWindow() if you don't like to use SetWindowPos().